# Упростить SQL запрос

Tags: sql

Написал рабочий запрос (выдает правильный результат). Но мне кажется, что его можно упростить, но я не вижу, как это можно сделать.

Схема базы данных

```
GOODS:
GOOD_ID int,
NAME varchar (20),
PRICE int, 
QUANTITY int,
PRODUCER varchar (20)
DEPT_ID int,
DESCRIPTION varchar(20).

SALES:
SALES_ID int,
CHECK_NO int,
GOOD_ID int (внешний ключ),
DATE_SALE date,
QUANTITY int.
```

Задание.
По каждой дате вывести информацию о суммарных выручках 1-го и 2-го отделов в формате: дата, суммарная выручка 1-го отдела, суммарная выручка 2-го отдела.

Мой запрос:

```
SELECT S1.DATE_SALE, SUM(S1.QUANTITY * G1.PRICE) AS revenue1,   
SUM(S2.QUANTITY * G2.PRICE) AS revenue2
FROM SALES S1, SALES S2, GOODS G1, GOODS G2
WHERE S1.DATE_SALE = S2.DATE_SALE AND S1.GOOD_ID = G1.GOOD_ID 
AND S2.GOOD_ID = G2.GOOD_ID
AND G1.DEPT_ID = 1 AND G2.DEPT_ID = 2 GROUP BY S1.DATE_SALE
UNION
SELECT S1.DATE_SALE, SUM(S1.QUANTITY * G1.PRICE) AS revenue1, 0 AS revenue2
FROM SALES S1, GOODS G1
WHERE S1.GOOD_ID = G1.GOOD_ID AND G1.DEPT_ID = 1 AND DATE_SALE NOT IN
(SELECT DATE_SALE FROM SALES S, GOODS G WHERE S.GOOD_ID = G.GOOD_ID 
AND G.DEPT_ID = 2) 
GROUP BY S1.DATE_SALE
UNION
SELECT S1.DATE_SALE, 0 AS revenue1, SUM(S1.QUANTITY * G1.PRICE) AS revenue2
FROM SALES S1, GOODS G1
WHERE S1.GOOD_ID = G1.GOOD_ID AND G1.DEPT_ID = 2 AND DATE_SALE NOT IN
(SELECT DATE_SALE FROM SALES S, GOODS G WHERE S.GOOD_ID = G.GOOD_ID 
AND G.DEPT_ID = 1) 
GROUP BY S1.DATE_SALE
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
select s.DATE_SALE,
  sum(if(DEPT_ID = 1, s.QUANTITY * g.PRICE, 0)) as revenue1,
  sum(if(DEPT_ID = 2, s.QUANTITY * g.PRICE, 0)) as revenue2
from sales s 
  join goods g on s.GOOD_ID = g.GOOD_ID 
where 
  g.dept_id in (1,2)
group by s.DATE_SALE
```

Comment: можно ускорить фильтром where DEPT_ID in (1,2). Мало-ли там отделов дюжина

Comment: @Ivan логично. поправил ответ.